# Is npm install package@latest stable or does it also include alpha/beta version?

Tags: npm

I just want some confirmation as I've always been using @latest for a while with my packages and want to know if I'm really installing a stable version or can possibly install a alpha/beta version of the package.

I'm pretty sure this is meant for stable versions as they tell you to install@latest for npm (unless it's special syntax like npm start).

The more I think about it, the more paranoid I get, any confirmation would be greatly appreciated. :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using `npm install <pkg>@latest` is equivalent to using `npm install <pkg>` by itself or listing `*` as the dependency version in package.json. npm documents this [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-tags#installing-with-tags):

> npm install  will use the latest tag by default.

So in practical terms, `latest` is semantically equivalent to `stable`.

However, if a prerelease version of a package is published to npm without specifying a prerelease tag such as `--beta` or `--rc`, that version becomes the `latest` by [default](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-tags#publishing-with-tags):

> By default, npm publish will tag your package with the latest tag.

As a result, it's possible to mess up and publish a prerelease version that will be installed by default. This happened to [Bootstrap](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/18520) in late 2015.

This [article](https://medium.com/@mbostock/prereleases-and-npm-e778fc5e2420) from early 2016 by Mike Bostock explains how even specifying `alpha` or `beta` as part of the version number won't prevent npm from making that version the `latest`.

So unfortunately if you want to be certain that you get only stable versions, you need to monitor this manually or trust the package developers to always specify a prerelease tag for non-stable versions.

You can also view the tags assigned for a package like this:

```
$ npm view express dist-tags
{ latest: '4.16.2', rc: '4.0.0-rc4' }
```