# How to update / upgrade Playwright?

Tags: node.js, playwright

What is proper way of updating/upgrading `Playwright` in `Node.js` project?
I tried to find this in official docs but I didn't found anything specific.

i.e. I have this simple project:

```
{
  "name": "cool-tests",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {},
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@playwright/test": "^1.28.1"
  }
}
```

What is best way of maintaining this project with newest `Playwright` version, together with the compatible browsers?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```bash
npm i @playwright/test
```

---

Playwright recommended full update command:

```bash
npm install -D @playwright/test@latest
```

`@latest` will update also major version (but is rare chance to happen that Playwright get 2.0 release)
also adding `@latest` prevent form improper release version (very rare situation https://stackoverflow.com/a/48038690)

`-D` option is for installing as **dev dependency** https://stackoverflow.com/a/22004559

---

Usually after Playwright update, browsers need to be updated with command:

```
npx playwright install
```

### Checking if Playwright package needs update:

```
npm outdated @playwright/test
```

The result may look like this

[image: image result of npm outdated @playwright/test]

Running `npm i @playwright/test` updates to **Wanted** and `npm i @playwright/test@latest` to **Latest**. No difference expected in this two in the near future

### Common problems

If command `npx playwright install` was not executed after update of Playwright version, and tests were run like:

```
npx playwright test
```

Then Playwright automatically recognize old browsers, throw error and propose installation of updated one.

```
 browserType.launch: Executable doesn't exist at 
 C:\Users\test\AppData\Local\ms-playwright\chromium-1041\chrome-win\chrome.exe



    ╔═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
    ║ Looks like Playwright Test or Playwright was just installed or updated. ║
    ║ Please run the following command to download new browsers:              ║
    ║                                                                         ║
    ║     npx playwright install                                              ║
    ║                                                                         ║
    ║ <3 Playwright Team                                                      ║
    ╚═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

There is no official docs regarding updating/upgrading, see https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/12179 for that.

### Useful commands regarding installation:

- Checking Playwright version:

  ```
  npx @playwright/test --version
  ```
- Update to specific version

  ```
  npm install @playwright/test@1.28
  ```
- Update to Canary Release (next release, published daily, treat it like beta) [docs](https://playwright.dev/docs/canary-releases)

  ```
  npm install @playwright/test@next
  ```
- Install latest official version

  ```
  npm install @playwright/test@latest
  ```

### Uninstalling Playwright

Uninstalling package

```
npm uninstall @playwright/test
```

Remove browsers installed from last installation

```
$ npx playwright uninstall
```

Remove all ever-install Playwright browsers

```
$ npx playwright uninstall --all
```

Answer (score 6):

You could do `npm i @playwright/test@latest` to get the latest version

and then `npx playwright install` to install browsers.